# Java program that uses pptx4j throws org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException

Tags: java, docx4j

I'm using sample code from [www.docx4java.org](http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/pptx4j/java/org/pptx4j/samples/CreateHelloWorld.java) to run the program that will create a powerpoint slide so that i can learn the use of the docx4j library. But it gives me an exception even tough i have already added both commons-logging-1.2.jar and commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar to my classpaths library as  (in which i also have apache-logging-log4j.jar, docx4j-3.2.1.jar, slf4j-nop-1.6.1 and slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar). This is the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.PresentationMLPackage.createPackage(PresentationMLPackage.java:169)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.PresentationMLPackage.createPackage(PresentationMLPackage.java:146)
at org.docx4j.samples.CreateHelloWorld.main(CreateHelloWorld.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 3 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Is there an incompatibility betweent the jars i am using or am i missing more jar files to work with pptx4j?

Originally i added docx4j-3.2.1.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar to work with [this sample code](http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/CreateWordprocessingMLDocument.java) that creates a word file. But with the pptx4j i haven't found a solution, shouldn't it work since i already have apache-logging-log4j and commons-logging-1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not throwing `org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException`, it's saying it can't find it:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException

You need to add Apache Commons Lang v2.x (not v3, that uses a different package name to the one the error mentions) to your classpath.

Comment: Further to this, use Maven, or manually add the deps in http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3.2.1.zip

Comment: @skaffman  i added commons-lang-v2.6 and it seems it now creates the slides but it gives me another exception, this time in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils

Comment: OK, so add commons-io also. The clue is in the error.